# DateTime Problem when saving to sharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

when choosing date and time from a view the sharepoint list adds auto +1 on the time why?
If i add 13:00 to 14:00 in the debugger it displays right but when, saving to the list, the list adds +1 on the time so the list displays 14:00 to 15:00 Why?

I am using SharePoint-Hosted App.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it has to do with the regional settings. 
Go to Site Settings, under Site Administration select Regional Settings and make sure the Time Zone is the correct one, and also locale (for date Display Format).